# Pushing out a PDF file to IE from an ASP.NET 3.5 site

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, .net-3.5, pdf

My application pushes out a PDF file to a popup (e.g. no menu/toolbar) browser window (in response to the user clicking a button).  This works for every browser out there except for IE7.  In IE7, all I get is a blank window.

Here is the server-side code that pushes out the PDF:

```
private void StreamPDFReport(string ReportPath, HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.Buffer = false;
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.ClearContent();
    context.Response.ClearHeaders();        

    // Set the appropriate ContentType.
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=Report.pdf");
    context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);        

    // Write the file directly to the HTTP content output stream.
    context.Response.WriteFile(ReportPath);
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    //context.Response.End();
}
```

On the client side, when the user presses the button, the following happens in the onClick handler:

onclick="window.open('RptHandler.ashx?RptType=CaseInfo', 'Report', 'top=10,left=10,width=1000,height=750')

Am I missing something really basic?  Why does it work in every browser but not IE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the following statement causes IE to not display the PDF:

```
context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

With IE7 we found you needed to add an additional header 'content-length' set to the size of the PDF your sending. something like:

Response.AddHeader("content-length", *{size of the pdf}*);

Comment: What you said is true, but that ain't it.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);` will only work when using IIS7.

I changed it to `context.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");` and it seems to be working with IE7 and IE8.